# Groovy object set property name conflict

Tags: groovy, sax

How do i resolve name conflicts between a setProperty called on a groovy object if the groovy object inherits from another class that also has a setProperty method
I am getting an error on the code below when I try to do the below, the error happens on the bold as XmlFilterImpl also has a similar setProperty method

```
def transitFileProcessorService
def BermudaOutputTransformFilter filter

public void transformBermudaOutput(File bermudaOutputFile)
{
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
    SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser()
    XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader()
    BermudaOutputTransformFilter filter = new BermudaOutputTransformFilter()
    filter.setParent(reader)
    **filter.transitFileProcessorService = transitFileProcessorService**
}


class BermudaOutputTransformFilter extends XMLFilterImpl{
    def relationshipId
   TransitFileProcessorService transitFileProcessorService
}
```

stack trace:
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'transitFileProcessorService' is not recognized.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.getProperty(AbstractSAXParser.java:2060)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try directly accessing the property with

```
filter.@transitFileProcessorService = transitFileProcessorService
```

Comment: This syntax also works to differentiate fields on a map from the entries within a map. I had to use a subclass of HashMap that added public fields, so `obj.id` was really calling `obj.get('id')`, `obj.@id` got the value of the field.